# How does one determine datalink capacity when ping is not given?

Tags: networking

Here's a link to my network diagram http://i48.tinypic.com/dcev0y.png

I am trying to learn on my own how to setup networks, and on the hybrid network parts I am confused, how does one calculate the amount of minimum datalink needed for a situation like the picture linked above.

English is not my primary language so it is hard for me to search for the proper keywords. Any help is kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible to do so it would be useful to ask the network provider how much [bandwidth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_%28computing%29) was available on each route and how much was currently being used.

If there is a network administrator in your organisation you should speak with them first.

This would be the easiest way to aquire an understanding the network topology in the diagram. But you would need to sensitive to the fact network administrators are typically very busy and under pressure so bear that in mind if you are asking for their time.

If you need to figure this out yourself you need to research and learn about **basic network monitoring tools**

Here are a list of concepts and tools that you should research and understand.
[ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_port) [ping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping), [traceroute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute), [nslookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nslookup) and [telnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet)

You will likely need to research [TCP/IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP), [network addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address) and [subnetting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetting)

In addition you will need to learn how about [network interfaces controllers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_interface_controller), multi-homing IP addresses, public and private facing IP addresses.

Comment: As we say at home, Qemal, ya have your work cut out for ya :) But what one person can do, another can do. Read lots and ask plenty of questions.

Comment: Thank you very much, i doubt i could have done this myself. I will gather info on what you told me, much appreciated.

Comment: It's a pleasure. Welcome to Stackoverflow.